# How to split string with accented characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, character-encoding, ruby-2.6

Currently I got :

```rb
"mɑ̃ʒe".split('')
# => ["m", "ɑ", "̃", "ʒ", "e"]
```

I would like to get this result

```rb
"mɑ̃ʒe".split('')
# => ["m", "ã", "ʒ", "e"]
```

Comment: Tip: In Ruby you don't need the empty `()`. You also probably meant `split('')` or `chars`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [String#each_grapheme_cluster](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_grapheme_cluster) instead. For example:

```
"mɑ̃ʒe".each_grapheme_cluster.to_a
#=> ["m", "ɑ̃", "ʒ", "e"]
```

Comment: Great Thanks a lot !

Comment: `"mɑ̃ʒe".grapheme_clusters` is the same.